# Send a variable with onblur

Tags: php, laravel, post, onblur

I have a field running an onblur function and need to send the value of that field is in the but really do not know how someone can give me a hand with that?

```
$condicion .= $nombremetadato['campoDocumentoPropiedad'].' = ? and ';
$condicion = substr($condicion, 0, strlen($condicion)-4);
$cond = ''; //This is the value I want Arrives from The Other Form
$consulta = DB::Select(DB::raw('SELECT '.$campos.' from '.$nombremetadato['tablaDocumento'].' where '.$condicion.''), array($cond));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focus in the browser window isn't really important when it comes to sending field data to a server. You should be more specific in your question, maybe post the code. Just get the field's values anyway, using its id/name attribute.

If you need to do some special processing WHEN the field is blurred, use something like:

```
    <input type="text" onblur="myFunction(this)" value="Value here!!">
```

to hook into a Javascript function, such as:

```
   <script>
                   myFunction(callerObj){
                               var val = callerObj.value;
                               // do something with val before submitting for processing by server
                   }
   </script>
```

Comment: You can plus me if you like the answer ;)